# Why am I getting this burn in effect with oscillating movement in p5.js?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, p5.js

I have a simple ellipse moving back and forth and [I keep getting this sort of "burn in" or "ghost trail" effect.](https://i.imgur.com/cYobq7f.mp4) What might be causing this?

Here is the code:

```js
let x = 50;
let y = 50;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  ellipse(x, y, 70, 70);
  x += 1 + (50 * sin(y));
  y += 2;
  if (x >= 500 || y >= 500) {
      x = 50;
      y = 50;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Though I don't know what you want your animation to look like, the 'ghosting' is caused by your circle's horizontal position which jumps back and forth between very extreme values, because you calculate the sine of numbers in increments of 2. `2 radians` are approximately 114 degrees which is really much. If you want a smooth movement you'd rather use a value of e.g. `0.1`. So set up an additional variable which keeps track of the phase.

Here's an example - not p5.js but the concept is the same:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let x = 50;
let y = 50;
let counter = 0;

function draw() {
    x = canvas.width / 2 + (50 * Math.sin(counter));
    y += 2;
    if (x >= 500 || y >= 500) {
        x = 50;
        y = 50;
    }
  
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    counter += 0.1;
}

setInterval(draw, 100);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Oh right I forgot the argument is supposed to be in radians not degrees ‍♂️. The question I'm still having though is why I'm seeing the ghost trail effect even though it's going super quickly: is it an optical illusion where it's going so fast and the brain's visual processing can't keep up or is the previous drawing of the ellipse *actually* still there on the redraw?